As I'm working on Gemini AI and I encounter a issue for token limit
I need to load a file and ask the Gemini LLM to answer the questions regrading from the loaded file.
I need to inject a 19kb JSON file. When I try to ingest the file, it says:
"raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10000 bytes."
I need to know how to increase the token limit of the Gemini LLM ?

Usually the limits are hardcapped, so you might have to break the file into parts and submit those.  You will have to post your code to this question if you want help on that (in text format not picture).

please edit your question and include your code. how are you loading this json file?
